# Adding mutiple but same keywords int value in python

Tags: python

Here i have json like this eg: `[{"passed_count": 24},{"passed_count": 22},{"passed_count": 0}]`

How can I add all the keywords "passed_count" key values only and store in a dictionary like this,

`result_dict = {"Passed": 46}`

so far I have done the following method but couldn't achieve,

```
    json.dump(runs, fp)
    with open('runlist.json') as json_file:
        for line in json_file.readlines():
            run_details = json.loads(line)
            result_dict = {}
            for keyword in run_details:
                pass_count = keyword["passed_count"]
                if keyword["passed_count"] not in result_dict:
                   result_dict["Passed"] = pass_count
                if keyword["passed_count"] in result_dict:
                   result_dict["Passed"] += pass_count
```

Comment: Your code does not even contain the addition operator (`+`) or `sum`. How is it supposed add up things?

Comment: @Selcuk, I tried the updated code

Comment: @iltech It would be better if you want the sum of all the specific keys- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720343/6075699

Comment: That's better. You have a logic error though; `keyword["passed_count"]` is an integer; why would it be `in` the `result_dict`? I guess you wanted to write `if "Passed" in result_dict:`... That being said, it is much easier to initialise it using `result_dict = {"Passed": 0}` right before the `for` loop and get rid of the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work as below, initiating dictionary values as 0 will solve this

```
   result_dict = {"Passed": 0}
   for keyword in run_details:
       pass_count = keyword["passed_count"]
       result_dict["Passed"] += pass_count
```

Answer (score 3):

I think must do it !?

```
with open('runlist.json') as json_file:
        for line in json_file.readlines():
            run_details = json.loads(line)
            result_dict  = {"Passed": sum([pc.get("passed_count",0) for pc in run_details ])}
            # do whatever with result_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

json.dump(runs, fp)
with open('runlist.json') as json_file:
    result_dict = defaultdict(int)
    for line in json_file.readlines():
        run_details = json.loads(line)
        for keyword in run_details:
            # ...
            pass_count = keyword["passed_count"]
            result_dict['passed_count'] += pass_count
```

Comment: this is not helping because I did the same method if you see my code above

Comment: No it is not:)  Read again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` to get sum of `passed_count` properties

```
objects = [{"passed_count": 24},{"passed_count": 22},{"passed_count": 0}]
reduction = {'passed': sum(item.get('passed_count', 0) for item in objects)}
#                               ^^^^^ use get() to avoid key error by providing a default value of 0

print(reduction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you might be overthinking your implementation.
You could try the following:

```py
import json

with open('runlist.json') as json_file:
    for line in json_file.readlines():
        run_details = json.loads(line)
        result_dict = {"Passed": 0}
        for keyword in run_details:
            if keyword.get("passed_count") is not None:
            result_dict["Passed"] += keyword["passed_count"]

print(result_dict)
```